# Deleted app still accessible via firebaseapp.com, how to stop that?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I tested firebase hosting by deploying a test app, but it wasn't working as expected (definitely I was doing something wrong). I deleted my app via the dashboard on firebase.com/account, but I still can access it via [appname].firebaseapp.com. Is there a way to delete the deployed app also? I can't use 'firebase delete-site' in my terminal because I don't have permission anymore after I deleted it on my dashboard.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Email support@firebase.com and we can help you there.